# Winterbash 2012 leaderboard

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

How can we see the leaderboard from last year's winterbash (2012)?

http://winterba.sh/leaderboard Seems to forward to the promos page now and not the old leaderboard.

Is there any way to get that information?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Winterbash 2012 is dead. Long live Winterbash 2013!

Comment: Seize the day my friends - the new hats are shiny. The old ones may have dissolved back into the pixels that wrought them.

Comment: Dead sounds... final. I prefer "the Winterbash 2012 hats are back in the closet, and the closet door is locked". :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd And what is found in closets? Skeletons. And what state are skeletons in? Dead. I rest my case :P

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the leaderboard for 2012 is no more. It was probably because it was maintained with some sort of updating cache and then queried for current value when visited. Once the values for 2012 were no longer relevant, the leaderboard no longer functioned. From what I can tell, the location of the 2012 leaderboard was changed into a redirect to the current Winter Bash url around May of 2013.

However, you can still see all the hats and what their requirements were at [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130509165304/https://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash) :) Love that place!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can go to [it's webpage](https://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash) and click the last thumbnail in the bottom. It loads a bit of the leaderboard, minus the names